# How to simulate setPanel of google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to create a table with the routes between 2 points without use setPanel() method? I'd like to show only the routes name and show the route in the map after a user click in the route's name.

See my code in: https://github.com/lusabo/xerekr

Thanks a lot,
Luciano

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gmap3 and did this way:

```
function showQuadro(results){
  var link;
  $("#rotas").html("");
  $.each(r.routes, function(key, value){
    link = "<a href='#' par='" + key + "'>" + value.summary + " - " + value.legs[0].distance.text + " - " + value.legs[0].duration.text +  "</a>";
    $("#rotas").append(link);
    $("#rotas").append("<br/>");
    $("[par=" + key + "]").live("click", function(){
                $("#map").gmap3(
                    {action:'clear'},
                    { action:'addDirectionsRenderer',
                        options:{
                            preserveViewport: true,
                            draggable: false,
                            directions: r,
                            routeIndex: key
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    }
```